# SQL server 2008 R2 - Backup doesn't end

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a small database (500 MB) with 10 tables. I can do select on all tables.

But when I do a backup, it is never ending. I have tried through the UI and also using the following command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE DB_NAME to
    Disk = N'C:\temp\DB_Aug22.bak
    With noformat, noinit, name = N'DB_Aug22.bak,
    STATS = 10
```

what am i doing wrong?

Regards,
Shiyam

Comment: Are your single-quotes problem just a typo on this question or did you copy-paste wrong?

Comment: I was copy pasting it wrong. 
But The problem was unfortunate. I killed the process and it was stuck. and I restarted MS SQL server service and it was stuck as well. Finally I had to reboot the server. All is good now. it is an SQL server quirk :).

Answer (score 1):

If you still face any issue in it, you can follow the approach (17 points):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Backup is very easy using the SSMS.

1. Go to database Right Click then Tasks----->Backup
2. Select what type of backup you want (log,diff,full) but log will be
   allowed if your recovery type is full not simple.
3. Just select where you want to keep this backup like
   ('D:/backup/full.bak') hit ok

This worked for me.